# how do i access powerpoint thumbnails using applescript

Tags: applescript, powerpoint, macos-sierra

I'm trying to use AppleScript to get the small thumbnail images from a PowerPoint presentation for every slide that has notes on its notes page. I can get the notes themselves, but I don't know how to access the small thumbnail images. I think it's in one of the three shapes on the notes page, but I'm stuck after that. The AppleScript dictionaries have me going in circles. PowerPoint 15 on a Mac running Sierra. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint doesn't expose the thumbnail images via the object model.

Instead, once you've determined that a slide has notes, use the Slide.Export method to create an image. It takes parameters that let you control the location, name, image format, and size of the file.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I code this? I don't see an export command in the PowerPoint dictionary, and I can't figure out how to programmatically tell PP to export a slide into an image.

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid. I do VBA but not AppleScript. In case it helps, Export is a method of the Slide object.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll let you know if I can figure it out.